# Is it safe to delete files in C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am on SharePoint 2013 and is it safe to delete huge files from my 'WebFrontEnd/Application Servers' and its around 17GB from the below location

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp
```

The last log file dates to 10/2/2015 and it started on 9/21/2015.

Comment: I guess yes, its safe to delete as its temporary. Lets wait for few more inputs from more experienced people here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typically it is safe to delete files from Temp folder, their are many process which created these temp files i.e timerjob, upgrade, etc. 
**The temporary files are not deleted when a process is completed.**

So you have to manually delete them. If a file is required by the SharePoint then it will not let you delete it, Because some process open that file or put a lock.

If you want to clean the temp folder, you can stop the sharepoint timer services then try to delete them.

here is reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678867(v=office.12).aspx